# Slider within a user control won't move

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a slider within a user control.  When testing it out, the slider won't move if it is kept within the user control but works outside of it.  Is there something that's needed to make it work?

The XAML for the usercontrol:

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,3,0" Grid.RowSpan="1">
                <TextBlock Text="15 mins" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Margin="0,-11,0,0" TextLineBounds="Tight" Foreground="White"/>
                <Slider Foreground="White" SmallChange="50" TickFrequency="50" LargeChange="50" Background="#BFFFFFFF" Value="50" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" StepFrequency="50" Maximum="100" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
                <TextBlock Text="1 hour" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Margin="0,-11,0,0" TextLineBounds="Tight" Foreground="White"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name="TimesList" DataContext="{Binding}" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Width="365" DataContext="{Binding}">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="29.333"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <Border Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderBrush="#B2FFFFFF" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2" Padding="0" Margin="-5,0,-5,-5"/>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Could you show us XAML code of you user control?

Comment: @ŁukaszRejman I've edited the post with the xaml for the usercontrol.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found that 60 pixels height is not enough for `Slider` control. That's why it doesn't work. But there are few easy ways to fix it. You can choose whatever fits your needs.

**Option 1**
Change the first row definition height to `Auto`. So the `Grid` will as high as the `Slider` control. It's 84 pixels.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

**Option 2**
The way you use `Grid` layout makes it pretty much the same as `StackPanel`. So you could also replace this `Grid` with `StackPanel`.

**Option 3**
You na change `Sldier`'s margins to fit 60 pixels height. Set the bottom margin to -24.

```
<Slider Foreground="White" SmallChange="50" TickFrequency="50" LargeChange="50" Background="#BFFFFFFF" Value="50" Margin="5,0,5,-24" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" StepFrequency="50" Maximum="100" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  I tried option 1 and it still doesn't seem to work.  Happen to have any other suggestions?